# The action of the Grothendieck group on higher K-theory groups

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

Let $(C,\otimes)$ be a monoidal (non symmetric) Waldhausen category. In particular, under these conditions,
$K_{0}(C)$ is a ring and $K_{i}(C)$ are $K_{0}(C)$-bimodule for any $i\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Suppose that $K_{0}(C)$ is a commutative ring. Let $a\in K_{i}(C)$ and $q\in K_{0}(C) $. I was wondering if $qa=aq$ ?

Comment: How does the monoidal structure interact with (co)fibrations and weak equivalences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this is not true in general. Let $R$ be a flat $k$-algebra with the two maps $K_1(R) \to K_1(R\otimes_k R)$ being different. For example, $R = k[t^{\pm 1}]$ for some nonzero ring $k$ and then the two maps differ on $GL_1$ and this can be used to detect the difference on $K_1$.

There is a monoidal Waldhausen category of the form $\bigoplus_n Perf(R^{\otimes_k n})$ whose $K$-theory is $\bigoplus_n K(R^{\otimes_k n})$.  If for all $n, K_0(R^{\otimes_k n}) = \mathbb Z$ (canonically, that is, with the obvious generator) then the $K_0$ is $\mathbb Z[t]$ and  is thus commutative. This happens, e.g. if $R= k[t^{\pm 1}]$ and $k$ is regular noetherian (say a field, for concreteness).

However, in this case, the action of $K_0(R)$ on the left or on the right corresponds, in low weights, to the map induced by either of the two inclusions $R\to R\otimes_k R$  and thus disagrees on $K_1$ by our very choice of $R$.

In fact, by truncating this example suitably, you can even make $C$ non-monoidally equivalent to $Perf(S)$ for some ring $S$.

Finally, let me point out that in a different direction, you can create examples using $\mathbb E_2$-ring spectra that don't admit an $\mathbb E_3$ structure.

Comment: I just realized that I do not understand the monoidal structure on the mentioned category… could you please define it? thanks !

Comment: It's something like a free monoidal category on $Perf(R)$ : the tensor product looks like $Perf(R^{\otimes_k p}) \times Perf(R^{\otimes_k q}) \to Perf(R^{\otimes_k n})$ whenever $p+q = n$, and this map takes $(M,N)\mapsto M\otimes_k N$

Comment: (It's an instance of $Perf(A)\times Perf(B) \to Perf(A\otimes_k B)$)